# NGINX configuration for multiple Docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, sveltekit

The system I'm working on consists of an SvelteKit app and a Flask App. Both are inside it's own docker container and a third one with an NGINX image.

The idea is that all requests that doesn't start with `/api` go to the SvelteKit app, and the ones that do go to the Flask app.

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;

    upstream backend {
        server backend:5002;
    }

    upstream frontend {
        server frontend:5001;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

After a lot of tries this is the config that is closest to the result I need but `/api` still goes to the SvelteKit app. So as I see it, I don't understand anything about how Nginx works.

This is the `docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
02e5f32f3b5f   stopssis_v2_nginx      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 minutes ago    Up 6 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp           nginx
4ebe13b534db   stopssis_v2_frontend   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   0.0.0.0:5001->5001/tcp, :::5001->5001/tcp   frontend
94345bfd5123   stopssis_v2_backend    "python ./app/run.py"    26 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   0.0.0.0:5002->5002/tcp, :::5002->5002/tcp   backend
```

Also, any good resource that explains nginx visually?

Comment: It seems like both `location` blocks should be inside the same `server` block; does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe take a look at the [nginx beginners guide](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html):

*Generally, the configuration file may include several server blocks distinguished by ports on which they listen to and by server names. Once nginx decides which server processes a request, it tests the URI specified in the request’s header against the parameters of the location directives defined inside the server block.*

Meaning that you should not have two separate `server` objects for routing traffic to different endpoints based on the path of the request. But instead you should put both `location` blocks inside the same `server` block, as they refer to the same *servername* and *port*.

Comment: The beginner guide, good resource. I wish I had some networking experience tho! Then for the same server I add the different location blocks right? Also, the upstream blocks are correct/necessary?

Comment: Nope, you use it if you have a multitude of endpoints (a cluster) you want to loadbalance between, read here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Comment: If you have a single endpoint you can directly reference it in proxy_pass